# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) Xamarin.Forms IOS

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I developed Web view To Navigate to web demo , URL is

`https://demos.xretail.com`

I edited info.plist with

```
  <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
      <key>www.the-domain-name.com</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
```

and i use paybass certificate in app delegate but it doesn't work for me

```
  ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Set <key>the-domain-name.com</key> instead of <key>www.the-domain-name.com</key>

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Can you access the url with the safari in your device?

Comment: @AmrKamal did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change `iOS` Build setting.

1. Change HttpClient implementation use **NSUrlSession**

Comment: where ssl/tsl implment option ?

Comment: Just change the Http client implementation I think that will solve the problem

Comment: can you try to add this keys <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key> <true/> <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key> <true/> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>

Comment: already added before i mentioned that above but didn't work for me